# Leaflet and mapbox traffic vector integration shows black map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, traffic

i want to display the Traffic information form mapbox on a map. 
Following is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
    <h1>Traffic</h1>
    <div id="mapidTraffic" style="height:512px;width:512px">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var streetLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<redacted>', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        });

        var trafficLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=<redacted>', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.mapbox-traffic-v1',
        });

        var mymapTraffic = L.map('mapidTraffic', { layers: [streetLayer] });

        var baseMaps = {
            "Streets": streetLayer
        };
        var overlayMaps = {
            "Traffic": trafficLayer
        };

        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(mymapTraffic);

        mymapTraffic.setView([49.4513412, 11.1306931], 13);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i click on "Traffic" in the Control then there is only a black background with some street-line. I want to see the street map too.

What must i do?

bets regards

Volkhard

Answer (score 0):

With [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/index.html) you are loading full map tiles on top of each other. Therefore, as the [Mapbox Traffic data](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-traffic-v1/) is made up only of traffic data, when you add the traffic layer you see the street lines (the traffic data) and a black background as there is no included base street map.

Instead, you should [create a new Mapbox style](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-custom-style/) which includes both a base street map and traffic data. You can then [load the tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-tiles) from this style when you want to see traffic data *and* the street grid. I have created a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/pj_leonard/pen/RwPeZew?editors=1000) which uses a Mapbox Style I created with both a Mapbox base street map and Mapbox Traffic data. Additionally, the code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
</head>

<body>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
  <h1>Traffic</h1>
  <div id="mapidTraffic" style="height:512px;width:512px">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var streetLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGxtYXBib3giLCJhIjoiY2tnaHl1Nm5kMGFuejMxbHYxdXNiZTdmaSJ9.NzXqTSavz0iRskwUmt5kPw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    });
    var trafficLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGxtYXBib3giLCJhIjoiY2tvdTNpd2s1MDlxMzJ4bXE2ajk4dGozcyJ9.zMjJBLrYRFLwEe2euOpG5g', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'plmapbox/ck860jimr0kf91ip8l61a5g00',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    });
    var mymapTraffic = L.map('mapidTraffic', {
      layers: [streetLayer]
    });
    var baseMaps = {
      "Streets": streetLayer
    };
    var overlayMaps = {
      "Traffic": trafficLayer
    };
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(mymapTraffic);
    mymapTraffic.setView([48.85341, 2.3488], 13);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox